# Is there any difference between Paid Windows 10 or Free Window 10?

Tags: windows

Is there any difference between [Paid Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-10-home/d76qx4bznwk4/1NT3) and **Windows** we download from internet or install from a dvd. Why the price of Windows is so high if, we can download it from internet? Is there any difference between working and quality in both?

If this is an off-topic then please send me a link of the StackExchange which is related to this question! 
I am currently using Windows 8 and my other laptop have a free Windows installed. I found no difference between them.

Comment: You're supposed to have a license no matter how you install it and from where. It can be an OEM license which is included with the purchase of the equipment or individual or volume licenses acquired independently of the hardware. Neither are free. If you don't have a valid license you're using "pirated" software.

Answer (score 6):

Windows is always supposed to be paid; it's just not always visible to the user.  If you buy a new PC from Dell in 2018, it includes Windows and the cost is included in the price.  For several years starting in 2015, if you had an old PC with purchased Windows 7 or 8, then the upgrade to Windows 10 was free.

However, the official "free upgrade" time period has ended.  For a time, you could still use the Disability Free Upgrade tool.  You may be able to use this tool in 2018 : https://www.zdnet.com/article/heres-how-you-can-still-get-a-free-windows-10-upgrade/ .

It is easy to download the modern Windows 10 ISO and create an installer USB stick or DVD.  It's also easy to install it.  You can choose "Skip" when prompted for your activation key.  However, after a few days, Windows will phone home to Microsoft to see if it's been paid for.  If not, it will post a little nagging text in the lower right hand corner, by the default clock position.

Microsoft keeps a large database of all of the different PCs that have had Windows 10 installed, using unique IDs from motherboard, CPU, and some other characteristics.  If it recognizes your PC as a paid one, it doesn't bother you.  If it does not recognize you, then you get the nagging text. (this can be removed)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any difference between Paid Windows and Windows we download from internet or install from a DVD.

The image distributed on the media, when you purchase Windows from an authorized reseller, is identical to that of the ISO that can be downloaded from Microsoft.  However, the image that is installed on OEM devices, is based on that default image but often is customized by the OEM.

> Why the price of Windows is so high if, we can download it from the internet? Is there any difference between working and quality in both?

When you purchase Windows, you actually only pay for the license itself, not the media to install it.  This has always been the case, but only recently, has Microsoft made it extremely easy to download Windows.  In the past, it was possible to download a Windows ISO directly, if you knew about where to find it.

> Is there any difference between working and quality in both?

The installation images are identical.

> I am currently using Windows 8 and my other laptop have a free window installed. And i found no difference between them?

Windows is not free.  OEM devices might come with Windows already installed but the cost of that license is built into the cost of the device.  While you could upgrade to Windows 10 for free, between July 2015 and July 2016, the cost of that license was simply integrated into the cost of your existing license.  The cost for a license is literally whatever Microsoft wants to charge for it.  Even during the free upgrade period, if you did not already have an eligible Windows license, a Windows 10 license was not actually free.

Answer (score 0):

The free upgrade have been ended since 2016, so it is an invalid system if you download directly from website without buying product key, and also it is weak for security. For paid Windows 10, we could have many choice such as Windows 10 home, Enterprise, Pro. Refer this link for checking the differences:https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows/compare But for free upgrade, it just upgrade to same edition such as Windows 7 pro to Windows 10 pro.